postgres jsonb get matching field
select  ((apply_json_data -> 'companyInformation') -> 'operationalAddress')->'state' as statvalue from sat_application_apply where statvalue = 'apple'
So i got a query that parses a jsonb field. The result of the parsing, I want to select all values where  the state is 'apple'
how do i do the comparison?
